# Use Swift Decoder to pull attributes from JSON array

Tags: json, swift, decoder, jsondecoder, swift-structs

I have a JSON array created using this call:

```
guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [Any] else {
    print("This is not JSON!!!")
    return
}
```

I am trying to get elements from the JSON objects in the array to display them using the following code:

```
struct sWidget: Codable{
    var createdBy: String
    var createdDate: Date
    var status: String
    var widgetNumber: String
    var updatedBy: String
    var updatedDate: Date
}


do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    for (index, value) in json.enumerated() {
        let currentWidget = try decoder.decode(sWidget.self, from: json[index] as! Data)
        let currentNum = currentWidget.widgetNumber
            //print(currentNum)
        widgetNums.append(currentNum)
    }
}
catch {
    print("decoding error")
}
```

The code compiles but when I run it I get this error in the output:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1063c34f8) to
>   'NSData' (0x1063c1090). 2018-08-09 09:41:02.666713-0500
>   TruckMeterLogScanner[14259:1223764] Could not cast value of type
>   '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1063c34f8) to 'NSData' (0x1063c1090).

I am still investigating but any tips would be helpful.

Comment: That's normal because `json` is already an Array of Dictionary/Array/String/Int, already serialized, so it won't have `Data` object inside it, so `json[index]` is not a `(NS)Data` object, so `json[index] as! Data` will crash. If you are just interetested in getting the numbers, send after `let widgets = jsonDecoder.decode([sWidget].self, data: content)`, do widgetNums.append(contentsOf: widgets.map{$0.widgetNumber}`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try that fetching objects like above mentioned? Because i see that you are using Codable. Fetching is very simple with that actually.

```
let yourObjectArray = JSONDecoder().decode([sWidget].self, data: json as! Data)
```

May be this line can be buggy but you can fetch them with one line.

Comment: I tried using this code but I get a warning about cast from [Any] to unrelated type 'Data' always fails

Comment: let yourObjectArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([sTruck].self, from: json as! Data)

Comment: @Jacobi are you using Alamofire for fetching data? This is a sample fetching func with Alamofire. I wish it will help you.

https://gist.github.com/Cemoo/3ed4f5a3eff11082b064e745d3ef6b35

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Cemal BAYRI's answer:

`JSONDecoder()` throws, so make sure to either us `try?` or `try` (don't forget `do-catch` with `try`)

```
guard let data = content as? Data else {
   return [sWidget]()
}

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
```

1. **try?**

```
let yourObjectArray = try? jsonDecoder.decode([sWidget].self, data: data)
```

2. **try**

```
do {
  let yourObjectArray = try jsonDecoder.decode([sWidget].self, data: data)
} catch let error {
}
```

**Note**: You would need to take care of `Data` and `Date` formatting. Below is an example for `Date`:

```
jsonDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
```

You can also check it out [here](https://github.com/nasirky/FlickrImageGallery/blob/develop/FlickrImageGallery/FlickrImageGallery/Network/Responses/Response%20Parsers/JSONResponseParser.swift)

Comment: let data = json as? Data is not populating data.  It is still nil after this line of code is executed

Comment: Here `json` is name of the variable containing data. From your question, it would be `content`.

Comment: content is already a Data type.  Am I replacing the Serialization call with the Decoding call?

Comment: Yes. The Decoder replaces Serialization plus all the other steps needed to convert json to models